# Terminals with customisable "open file uri" feature (Linux)

Tags: vim, terminal, tmux

A lot of terminal applications can open file uris in the default editor (e.g. vscode).

This is a great feature but it doesn't suit my workflow. Here is why.

My editor of choice is terminal vim inside a tmux window. I run some tests in another tmux window and often get failures with a stacktrace. I'd like to click on a file path in that stacktrace and get switched to the vim window with that file open on that line.

When I was on OSX I managed to get this sort of working in an iTerm (details [here](https://gist.github.com/artemave/e68aa6e367f2c65aece6300f44aacb5a))

Does anybody know of a terminal application that has capabilities to customize this behavior?

P.S.
I requested this feature in alacritty and it generated [some discussion](https://github.com/jwilm/alacritty/issues/2051) but that's about it.

Comment: I believe rxvt-unicde (urxvt) has a plugin framework that would potentially allow you to make this work as long as you could write a script that could do the dirty work given a url.  Some more info here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/rxvt-unicode#Clickable_URLs.  Additionally it looks like you could potentially write your own extension if the existing URL matching extension isn't good enough.  I suspect that the default matcher plugin would work fine given the info here https://linux.die.net/man/1/urxvt-matcher.

Comment: @RandyMorris this works great, but there is one problem with urxvt-matcher that is a show stopper: the matching is always on. For example, I don't want any matching when I am in vim. If only there was a way to toggle it on - e.g. when a certain key is pressed.